# How to create conditional stages in datasatge rpoject?

Tags: datastage

I am having a requirement like: If my ODBC connector stage returns results then go to transformer stage, if my ODBC connector stage doesn't returns any result, I am planning to notify to customer with email. Could any one you please let me know how can achieve this in one job?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sequential stages and make triggers according to the result

Comment: I need to modify the existing parellel jobs.